# Advice me what to do with large project when you work alone !

Tags: asp.net

I bet many of you were in such situations in the past.

I'm currently working on huge ASP.NET web project. Ad management system of some kind. My boss doesn't want to get more professionals to help me but gives me inexperienced staff that don't even know to program on ASP.NET and think it is an easy task. I deal with programming and design

What advices do you have to handle the boss ?

What tools can help me to ease with this task ( except usage of this very website )?

Thanks

Comment: Edited: Removed offensive language - I know you are frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What advices do you have to handle the boss ?

First make sure you have a good analysis document and that you have for every dependency a *spoc* (single point of contact). Make sure the people who you're making this application for are integrated into the process. I suggest using something like scrum but certainly daily standup meetings.

Use a good system to follow up on everyone like for example TFS2010 which has also testing capabilities integrated so your testing team can be better integrated.

Have a bug tracking tool and source safe handy. Continuous integration is also an asset.

> but gives me inexperienced staff that don't even know to program on ASP.NET

It's your boss intention to upgrade his people to a level where they are capable of programming ASP.NET applications in the end. What way to better learn it than hands on experience from a dedicated professional like you?

Be aware: you're dealing with people now, not just code. They get sick, have their strenghts and weaknesses just like you. And believe me, it can be a challenge sometimes to deal with the human part of a project. Especially when there's pressure due to release dates.

Comment: There is no staff. I'm the staff and QA team. Boss offers me programmers that he knows. One of them is person who's experience in programming ends up with copy pasting contact form in PHP.

Comment: @eugeneK ASP.NET is pretty intuitive and easy to learn if you've programmed before. Unless you have a very tight schedule for your project - you can guide those inexperienced programmers. I bet that after a week or so they will be able to help you with simple tasks...

Comment: `Boss offers me programmers that he knows`. Yes I know. And I also know it's your bosses wish that you make them more competent in the end. `One of them is person who's experience in programming ends up with copy pasting contact form in PHP`. And that's already a start. Now it's up to you to learn them what webforms, user controls, the page life cycle, postback, ... are. Really try to stop being frustrated and just sit down and talk with your team. You might end up being surprised with what they can do. It's your task to make them a team and capable developers.

Answer (score 1):

I would hope good source control is something you already haev on your list but I think its always the best thing for any big project. Keeps your code safe and has the added advantage of allowing easy review of what your team are checking in if you feel the need for oversight.

Other than that just make sure you give your boss a realistic understanding of the time taken for various tasks and if he complains make it clear that your team needs more training if he wants stuff done faster.

P.S. [Edit: removed as no longer relevant]

Comment: How else person with zero experience in programming who claims that can do this system in few weeks should be called? Just visited Wikipedia and under Mental Retardation there is a list of symptoms, 4 from which appear in those "inexperienced" staff members

Comment: I have no problem with you calling them incompetent or anything else but Mental Retardation is a serious medical condition which I would be willing to bet these people don't suffer from.

Comment: sorry, must be frustration as Daniel mentioned.

Comment: That's cool. Now its gone from the main post I'll edit out my PS as its no longer relevant. If you want I'm happy to remove this comment thread as well to put it all behind us. I know how frustration like that feels though, you have my sympathy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could ask him for a raise from getting rid of the people who are not helpful. that might actually save him money and make your time more worthwhile.

Comment: +1 Sometimes one head is better than two.  You could call it an economy of scaling back.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convince him to distribute some (technical...) parts of the project to RentAcoder.com or getAfreelancer.com? It will be cheaper than getting more manpower..

Comment: Which will make me sort of project manager as i will need to define what those freelancers should do. Full time job from my experience.

Comment: `It will be cheaper than getting more manpower..` But take into account the extra cost of following up, testing, contract management, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a decent workitem/bugtracking system. This won't turn your 'inexperienced devs' into experts but at least you'll be able to see what progress they are making(or not making as the case may be)